# How can I create a simple ListView Shopping List?

Tags: android, android-listview, shopping-cart

I want to create a very simple version of a shopping list within my app. This page will be separated with an EditText at the top in order to add in the shopping items and then a ListView below displaying all of the items. I want the simplest way to develop this and hopefully without having to clutter my database anymore. However I do want this list to be displayed every time the app is opened and be able to add and delete items whenever necessary. Therefore if it is possible to store the data in some other way, this would be preferable. The items will each be Strings and only about 20 characters long at maximum.

I did create a version that used an Array and this worked perfectly, other than the fact that the data had been wiped when the app was restarted.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this or example code would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you should use Database to store data. As mentioned above, Shared preference are used to store only small and uncomplicated data. Usually shared preference store settings of an application or some key values. Data for listview is usually stored in database, because your listview may contain 10000 items in future.

refer [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for storage option

use of listview with database is shown [here](http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/android-list-view-from-database-with-cursor-adapter/)

refer [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) for database

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to use an array, you can store your array in SharedPreferences. That way it won't be wiped out when you restart your app.

Read the part about [using SharedPrefences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

It's my favorite way of storing small uncomplicated data.